に聞く How to differentiate source from action
So the thing is I kind of understand how it works like in these sentences:
うわさに聞いたとおり腐った空間だな
Just like I heard from the rumor
(Source)
彼女に聞いた
Asked her
(Action done towards someone)
But how does on differentiate? I feel ''to ask'' and ''to hear from'' are very different words. Would one have to just decipher from context and just let it be?

Whether 彼女に聞いた translates to "(I) asked her" or "(I) heard from her" depends on the context. In most cases, the correct meaning can be understood from the context, but when you really need to distinguish between the two meanings, you can also say 彼女に尋ねた for "asked" and 彼女から聞いた for "heard". Of course, 彼女に聞いてください, 彼女に聞こう, ChatGPTに聞いた and so on always refer to actively asking.
On the other hand, when the "information source" is not a human, we almost always use で to mark it. We say ニュースで聞いた or 新聞で知った, not ニュースに聞いた or 新聞に知った. As an exception, 噂に聞く is a set phrase with a slightly literary ring, and you have to remember its nuance. While 噂で聞く means hearing something directly through a certain rumor, 噂に聞く is somewhat vague, and it often has the connotation of "which I often hear about", "that famed" or "the well-known". The information source isn't necessarily a concrete rumor.

噂に聞く高尾山にやってきた。
I've come to the well-known Mount Takao.
I've come to the much-talked-about Mount Takao.
I've come to Mount Takao, which I've heard so much about.
噂で聞いた高尾山にやってきた。
I've come to Mount Takao, which I heard about from a (specific) rumor.

In your case, うわさに聞いたとおり腐った空間だな sounds like this information is generally circulating within a certain community, while うわさで聞いたとおり腐った空間だな tends to suggest the speaker obtained this information from a specific rumor. (The difference is not always important, though.)

I see so it's context dependent and に is more a general term ''from'' while で is ''by /through a specific rumor''

@HoodIntercooledSubaru You need to learn how to use this type of で, but I think it's best to remember 噂に聞く as a special set phrase with a unique usage. Even if you've only visited a place after seeing it in a guidebook or YouTube video, you might still say "これが噂に聞く◯◯か!" ("So this is the famous ◯◯!").

I would assume the で here is the means of the action but I guess it's fair that 噂に聞く is an exception or a set phrase as you said.
